# Google App Engine showing a lot of 204 and I can't get any log

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using google app engine with Python
A lot of my users are getting return code 204 (I can see on the Stackdriver log)

It's the same page (that returns a json that comes from datastore) and for some reason sometimes it's returning 204 (no Content) even thought there are valid contents.

I have try...catches on my get method and they are never triggered.
I have logging lines like: logging.info(u'right in the begging of method') 
and they aren't printed when the return code is 204.

I get this kind of entry on the log viewer:

> 179.236.114.131 - - [04/Jan/2017:03:26:50 +0000] "GET /querywg?date=2017-01-04&categoria=filme&app_type=free HTTP/1.1" 204
>   117847 - "okhttp/3.4.1" "gtvbrapp.guiatvbr.com.br" ms=19 cpu_ms=0
>   cpm_usd=0.000013170428 loading_request=0 instance=-
>   app_engine_release=1.9.48 trace_id=4c71730e72178c723437b2f196f44166

All of them have the `instance=-` instead of a long number.

Any ideas?

The get() method (and dependencies):

```
def getAllOperadoras(self):

  ret = []
  operadoras_query = OperadorasList.query().order(-OperadorasList.lastupdate).fetch(1)

  for ops in operadoras_query:
      return ops.listaOperadoras

  return '[]'

  def getOperadora(self, id):

    operadora = Operadoras.get_by_id(id)

    if(operadora):
        return operadora.canaisJson

    return '[]'


 def get(self):

    idOperadora = self.request.get('id')

    ret = ''
    if(idOperadora):
        ret = self.getOperadora(idOperadora)
    else:
        ret = self.getAllOperadoras()

    self.response.headers['Cache-Control'] = "public, max-age=%d" % constants.CACHE_CONTROL_SIZE
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    self.response.out.write(ret)
```

the app.yaml:

```
application: some-invented-id
version: 7
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
instance_class: F2
threadsafe: true

env_variables:

handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /font
  static_dir: font

- url: /data
  static_dir: data
  mime_type: application/json

# Endpoints handler
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: services.APPLICATION

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: 1
  upload: robots.txt

- url: /.*
  script: mainpage.app
  secure: optional

builtins:
- deferred: on
- appstats: on
- remote_api: on

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
```

Comment: maybe show us your `get()` method?

Comment: And also your app.yaml?  Is the right script being called by the handler?

Comment: the get method and the app.yaml I can post, but they work (I don't know the % of times because I don't know where to find it in the dashboard).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

204 means your files is cached and handled by the Google Edge cache, if you don't want this resource to be cached please set http header `cache-control: no-cache`

Comment: I failed solving it with `expiration` and `default_expiration` in app.yaml, but I could control `cache-control: public, max-age=240` with explicitly setting `send_from_directory(app.static_folder, request.path[1:], cache_timeout=240)`